# What are the advantages of using ClojureScript for both server and client sides, without any Clojure/JVM?

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

Is putting away the JVM a good thing in certain ways? How so?

I read some cons about the JVM (Slow startup time, lack of TCO) but still feel I need a deeper understanding...

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Putting away? Like in the attic?  Voted to close. Not constructive.

Comment: It's not about avoiding JVM, it is about working seamlessly (in the same language) to hit both front and back ends. Think about ClojureScript "without JVM" as a JavaScript "with Browser runtime". I don't think SO is good at all at "closing questions", but I can see why people would vote to close this, as the question is not quite clear. A better way would be to "vote to _clarify_" rather than _close_ though.